# Three.js bend PlaneGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm new to `three.js` and currently trying to bend a plane.

It works fine, but I don't know how to 3D bend a plane at all - just like the bend of this one, but in the opposite direction (ignore perspective etc. - just the bend):

[image]

```
this.width = window.innerWidth;
this.height = window.innerHeight;

this.geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(this.width, this.height);

this.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: this.texture,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
});

this.plane = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry, this.material);

this.scene.add(this.plane);
```

What's the correct approach? Where do I start?

Comment: Could you not use a cylinder geometry with start/end angles if you need such a shape?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I'm new to the whole 3D thing, I'll give it a try! Thanks.